# Is it possible to use Amazon S3 for folder in a .net site

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, storage

Is it possible to use Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) for folders & files on a .net site?

*Background:*
I have 200 websites sites and I would like to have a single common code base. Right now they are on a single dedicated server. I plan to move them to an EC2 server.

As you can see, some of the folders & files are *not* on S3 and some are.

[image]

**Admin Panel** - is a folder that requires authentication - is this an issue?

**/Bin/** - contains DLL's - is this an issue?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say,"uses S3" do you mean that S3 is serving the files to the end user?

Comment: You don't serve a DLL to an end-user.
The files are mostly aspx pages. 90% dynamic content (aspx pages, dlls), only 10% is static (images, css, js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 is normal Windows Server like your current dedicated server. You remote desktop into it, install whatever you need, setup IIS etc.

S3 on the other hand is **just a storage device**. Think of it like a big NAS device. So you can use it to serve your static content (possible in conjunction with Cloudfront) but the actual website (Dlls, aspx pages etc) will have to be on EC2 in IIS.

Comment: I found that I can create "virtual directories" on the IIS sites, then point them to a "template" folder on the same server. I wonder if this "template" folder could be the S3 storage device?